# Parse LocalDataStore queries give Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread

Tags: multithreading, parse-platform, local-datastore

I'm developing an Objective C application using Parse.  I understand why, when I make a Parse query to the server, that I would need to perform the query in background and run code in a completion handler / callback when that call has completed.  And this is what I do when I initially launch the app and download some data tables.

However, I then pin all these Parse objects locally and subsequently make queries to this data using the LocalDataStore option.  Do I still need to execute these calls in background?  If I remove the background option with these calls, the code runs fine but I still get the warning in the console:

*Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.*

If I'm performing local Parse queries can I treat this simply as a warning (and ignore it) or do I still need to treat these queries as operations that should be performed in a background thread ?  Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.